Manipulate dom content in JavaScript in single page app
I need to append div element contains p and h3 after component tag in Angular
<product-list >
When put it inside window.onLoad()
Works only when reload and refresh
That approach isn't used in single page app
How can do that?
I don't have access for ts and html, I can only add custom script
I expect that Tag will dispaly when navigate to product list

You need to edit your question to add more context:

the code you're using to add this component
the code you were using that didn't work as you intended
why other solutions to similar problems on this website didn't work for you

This can help think of a solution to your problem.

Use mutation observer to track when the component is added to the body.
Observe document, and when an element is added, check by tag name if it's the one you need, and then do your thing.
Make sure you have component's exact tag name (use component's selector value), and to insert/run this script before angular code runs:
<!-- place before angular code -->
<script>

  // use exact component's `selector` value
  const tagName = 'app-product-list';

  const observer = new MutationObserver( (mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((el) => {
            // get tag name and see if it's the one      
      if (el.addedNodes?.item(0)?.tagName?.toLowerCase() === tagName) {
        
        // if it's one time action, disconnect observer
        //observer.disconnect();

        console.log('got it, now do your thing');
        
        // you have the elmenent here, you could do 
        // el.addedNodes?.item(0).after(document.createElement('div'));
        
        //doYourThing();

      }
    });
  });


  observer.observe(document, {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    characterData: false,
    subtree: true,
  });

</script>

<app-root></app-root>

<!--ng script modules: runtime, main etc....-->

